# Removing deprecated realms

Tags: android, realm, ubuntu-16.04

I have a number of now obsolete realms I want to remove from my ROS (running on ubuntu).
removing the associated test-users did not help, the realms are still there... how can I remove them (either using the web interface http://localhost:9080/#!/realms or by shell command)

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to remove a Realm via the UI. This is a small oversight in our feature set, and will be addressed in the coming weeks.